# Modifiying ANTLR v4 auto-generated lexer?

Tags: antlr, javac, lexer

So i am writing a small language and i am using antlrv4 as my tool. Antlr autogenerates lexer and parser files when u compile your grammar file(.g4). I am using javac btw. I want my language to have no semicolons and the way i want to do this is: if there is an identifier or ")" as the last token in a line, the lexer will automatically put the semicolon(Similar to what "go" language does). How would i approach something like this? There are other things like ATN(which i think is augmented transition network) and dfa(which i think is deterministic finite automaton) in the lexer file which i don't understand or how they relate to the lexing process?. Any help is appreciated. (btw i am still working on the grammar file so i don't have that fully completed).

Answer (score 0):

Several points here: the ATN and the DFA are internal structures for  parser + lexer and not something you would touch to change parsing behavior. Also, it's not clear to me why you want to have the lexer insert a semicolon at some point. What exactly do you want to accomplish by that (don't say: to make semicolons optional in the parser, I mean the underlying reason).

If you want to accept a command without a trailing semicolon you can make that optional:

```
assignment: simpleAssignment | complexAssignment SEMI?;
```

The parser will give you the content of the assignment rule regardless whether there is a trailing semicolon or not. Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't want semicolons because i believe they are mainly for parsers right? I thought about what u suggested, making it optional in the parser grammar but semicolons also mark the end of a line or statement. For example: let's say i have print p5abc and than in next line i have print 10. how would the parser know the print 10 in the next line isn't part of the string from the first line. i.e the string isnt p5abcprint10 ? By adding semicolons automatically, i can omit their use from the programs while still keeping the functionality of the semicolons? i hope that makes sense. :(